# Creating map flags with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have a requirement where I need to create a map flag based on a users avatar:

[image]

The users avatar can be any size and aspect ratio.  The problem I'm having is getting the image to compose correctly, allowing me to get the transparency around the marker in order to support the tick at the bottom.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It transpires that this is fairly straightforward with the correct approach.

First you need TWO overlay images. One of these is the size of the result image and is transparent everywhere for except where you want the avatar to show.  The second is a simple transparent PNG of the surround on the image.

Then, this seems to work:

```
composite avatar.jpg -thumbnail 61x68^ -gravity center map_marker.png mask.png output.png
```